# UIScrollview loses its top contents when I move the containing view up with the keyboard ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have been pulling my hair out trying to fix this problem the last few weeks. I move up the entire view contained in my view controller when the  keyboard appears. Once I do so the top portion of my scrollview contained in the view becomes unreachable. It is like the top of the screen is cutting off the top portion of my scrollview. Is there some way to fix this?

```
//Move the keyboard when you select a textfield.
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification{

CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

CGRect viewRect = self.view.frame;
viewRect.origin.y = -215;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^ {
    self.view.frame = viewRect;
    }];
scrollBounces = YES;
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

This is all that I am doing to the view that contains the scrollview.

Comment: Can you add screenshot when keyboard is there ?

Comment: Also add the screen shot what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` for the scrollView too:

```
[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(215, 0, 0, 0)];

[scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(215, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that I overlooked setting the inset! You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Write the below three lines in the keyboardWillShow

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kKeyboardHeightValue, 0.0);
self.mDisplayedScrollview_.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.mDisplayedScrollview_.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
```

Write the below three lines in the keyboardWillHide

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.mDisplayedScrollview_.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.mDisplayedScrollview_.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
```

Comment: This approach works for me on iOS 7 but not on iOS 8. Any ideas what's up? Do I need to force a layout update?